# Change color of text when music is playing

Tags: iphone, xcode

i'm newbie in Xcode programming :)
I want to create a karaoke software running in iPhone. This software will display a lyric of midi or mp3 files. But now I have a problem that I can't change color of each word in the sentence of lyric
I search in Web and they tell me using OpenGL ES or change color of each pixel of word to do that
Can anybody help me to solve this problem? or suggest me how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here, nobody is there to code a script for you. When you face a problem, first do some research (use google, search this site itself, etc.) Then you'll definitely come to a general idea of what your problem might be. Now apply your research in your work. See if it works or not. If there is no luck, do not hesitate to ask your question here. Programmers from all around the world will be more than happy to guide you further. (You will be able to show them what you have done so far by then) :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with iOS 6, you can use a `UILabel` or a `UITextField` or a `UITextView` to display an attributed string.  In an attributed string, you can assign different colors to different parts of the string.  For example:

```
NSString *text = @"Raindrops on roses and whiskers on kittens";
NSMutableAttributedString *trib = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
    initWithString:text];
// trib's characters will all be drawn in black by default
[trib addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor]
    range:NSMakeRange(13, 5)];
// Now the five characters starting at offset 13 (“roses”) will be drawn in red.
```

Apple had two sessions at WWDC 2012 about using attributed strings:

- [Session 222 - Introduction to Attributed Strings for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/#222)
- [Session 230 - Advanced Attributed Strings for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/#230)

I suggest you watch the videos.

Answer (score 0):

Question is too broad, but you can start with this perhaps:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.foo.com/lyricspage.txt"];
NSString *webPageString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]init];

label.text = webPageString;

label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```